# Can't find the Syntax Error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing a simple text based RPG game and I'm trying to get the inventory system to work.  I've copied verbatim the working code starting from, but I get a Syntax Error.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong as it looks good to me.  Sorry for the newbie question.  Thank you!

```
class Container(object):

        def__init__(self, name):
                self.name = name
                self.inside = {}

    def__iter__(self):
            return iter(self.inside.items())

    def__len__(self):
            return len(self.inside)

    def__contains__(self, item):
            return item.raw in self.inside

    def__getitem__(self, item):
            return self.inside[item.raw]

    def__setitem__(self, item, value):
            self.inside[item.raw] = value
            return self[item]

    def add (self, item, quantity=1):
            if quantity < 0:
                    raise ValueError("Negative quantity.  Use remove() instead.")

            if item in self:
                    self[item].quantity += quantity
                    self[item].recalc()

            else:
                    self[item].quantity -= quantity
                    self[item].recalc()
```

and I get the following error when I run it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "game.py", line 2, in <module>
    from characters.player import *
  File "/home/dave/Projects/rpg-master/characters/player.py", line 4, in <module>
    from items.container import *
  File "/home/dave/Projects/rpg-master/items/container.py", line 4
    def__init__(self, name):
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Space after `def` in `def__init__(self, name):`, etc.

Comment: put space after def in all the function declarations.

Comment: Note that using a good editor with syntax highlighting should make a mistake like this immediately obvious.

Answer (score 10):

You don't have spaces after `def`:

```
def__init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.inside = {}
```

should be

```
def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.inside = {}
```

and so forth for the rest of the class functions.

Comment: Yes, and as @PauloBu [says](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16845007/2423516), make sure that your code is well indented.

Comment: Thank you all very much.

Comment: I added some comment about indentation in my answer. Hope it will be useful.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, `__init__` is not well indented. Second, you should separate the `def` keyword from the actual method name:

```
class Container(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.inside = {}

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.inside.items())

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.inside)

    def __contains__(self, item):
        return item.raw in self.inside

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.inside[item.raw]

    def __setitem__(self, item, value):
        self.inside[item.raw] = value
        return self[item]
```

**UPDATE:** Notice that you're mixing indents, python normally suggest 4 white spaces for indenting, but I see you're using both 4 and 8, you may use whatever you want but stick to it, don't mix them because you may find unexpected behavior.

Hope this helps!